# Checkbox inside a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to add a checkbox control insida a datatalbe. then i binded this datatable to the gridview control.
The following code i used

```
Datatable dt=new Datatable();
dt.columns.add("Action");
dt.Rows.Add(typeof(CheckBox));
grdi1.datasource=dt;
grid1.databind();
```

When i used the code like this, in runtime instead of getting a checkbox i'm getting
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox in the column specified.

How i need to achieve to get a checkbox inside a datatable.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: try to add new 'CheckBox' instead of 'typeof(CheckBox)'

Comment: Use teamplate column in which put checkbox control in gridview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to specify boolean type column field when you add column to datatable, specify either 0 or 1 while adding rows. following code may work.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Action", typeof(bool)));            
    dt.Rows.Add(0);
    dt.Rows.Add(1);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this was the simplest explanation I've seen thus far!

Answer (score 0):

You can use template columns:

```
<ItemTemplate>  
     <asp:checkbox id="checkBox" runat="server" checked='<%# Eval("theColumn") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

The above code only works for one-way binding. You have to get the values from checkboxes by yourself.